# How can I use grep to find the output of command

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I am trying to cycle through some ports for connecting via ssh. New to shell/bash not quite sure how to accomplish this.

```
startingPort=xxxx
endingPort=yyyy

ssh(){
ssh admin@localhost -p $startingPort
}
```

the output of an invalid port is ssh: connect to host localhost port 8801: Connection refused
I need to capture this and then try the next port in the range

I am trying to iterate through the port numbers until i see 
    Password authentication
    Password:

Answer (score 1):

To get the output of the ssh command, you can check it with "$?".
As an example, if you want to log errors :

```
//inside the loop (of muzido answer)
ssh admin@localhost -p $port
if [ "$?" -ne 0 ] ; then
    //write into logfile
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you muzido and Theo Pnv; the two answers combined helped me get this task accomplished..

```
log_file=/directory/log_file.txt
startingPort=8801 
endingPort=8899
port=''

sshToStuff(){
for (( port=$startingPort; port<=$endingPort; port++ ))
do
if [ "$?" -ne 0 ] ; then
    echo "`date -u`" " ssh: connect to host localhost port $port: Connection refused" >> $log_file2;
fi


ssh admin@localhost -p $port
done
}
sshToKaraf
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this;

```
#!/bin/bash
startingPort=10
endingPort=40

for (( port=$startingPort; port<=$endingPort; port++ ))
do
ssh admin@localhost -p $port
done
```

Comment: That handles the looping part but not the parsing of the output.

Comment: This will work as far as getting it to iterate through until I find the correct port.  I do need to log out each failed attempt so I need to capture this line "ssh: connect to host localhost port 8801: Connection refused" for every port refused, which I will echo >> intoLogFile